# Calculating U(f,$P_0$) and L(f,$P_0$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Consider f(x) = {5 if x=1, 2 if x$\neq$1

Let $\epsilon$ > 0. Consider the partition of [0, 10] given by $P_0$ = {0, 1-$\epsilon\over{12}$, 1+$\epsilon\over{12}$,10}. How much is U(f,$P_0$) and L(f,$P_0$)?

For L(f,$P_0$), I have the following, but am not sure if I am doing it correctly:

2($\epsilon\over{12}$) +5 (10 - (0+$\epsilon\over{12}$)) = 50 - $\epsilon\over{4}$.

Comment: Write down the formula for the upper and lower sum. I want to make sure you have got that part right, because the rest is just calculations.

Comment: Ok, one second.

Comment: Many many seconds, don't worrry, I am here a long time.

Comment: I actually don't see the definition in my notes. Was going off an example. I do have though, that the upper integral from a to b is inf{U(f,P):P is a partition of [a,b]}

Comment: and similarly for lower integral, but with supremum

Comment: Should I post the example?

Comment: No worry, I am answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the partition is fixed, right? So $L(f,P_0)$ depends on $P_0$.

The definition of $L(f,P_0)$ is the following: Suppose that $P_0 = [x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $x_0=0$ and $x_1=10$ (in this case), and $x_i \neq x_j$. Then, the lower sum $L(f,P_0)$ is defined by:
$$
L(f,P_0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-x_{i-1}) \inf_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]} f(x)
$$
And the upper limit is defined as:
$$
U(f,P_0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-x_{i-1}) \sup_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]} f(x)
$$

Hence, since $P_0 = [0,1-\frac{\epsilon}{12},1+\frac{\epsilon}{12},10]$, we get that:
$$
L(f,P_0) = 2\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right) + 2\left(\frac{2 \epsilon}{12}\right) + 2\left(9-\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right)
$$

(Take the differences, and note that the value $5$ is taken at $x=1$, so the infimum of $f$ is $2$ in each interval).

This simplifies to:$$
L(f,P_0) = 20
$$

as you can check.

Similarly, in the upper sum, only the supremum of the middle interval changes to $5$.
So:
$$
U(f,P_0) = 2\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right) + 5\left(\frac{2 \epsilon}{12}\right) + 2\left(9-\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right)
$$

Hence the upper sum evaluates to:
$$
L(f,P_0) = 20 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

As you can check.

To see that the function is integrable, see that when $\epsilon \to 0$, then $U(f)$ and $L(f)$ coincide, hence the function is integrable, and it's integral is $20$.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @JohnH You are welcome.

Comment: If I were to subtract the two, would I put $\epsilon\over{2}$ or just 0?

Comment: If I had to put a numerical value on it

Comment: You would put $\frac {\epsilon}2$ for an exact answer.